# Image database - storage in cloud and managed database

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, image, storage

So for the past month or so I've been on the look out for a good way of storing images in the cloud (Azure).
My conclusion is that have an endpoint to receive the original image - store the image on a filesystem, register the image in database + some meta data.
Use imagemagick to save various sizes

Most tutorials I find are regarding saving images to blob storage (not interesting)
I found one python repository that does exactly as I want - however it's python 2.7 (https://github.com/aroess/image-database)

and then I see others are using expensive 3rd parties

Am I googling wrong or sth ? I want something similar to whatever the large image based websites have (9gag, reddit etc) and I know something like Drupal does it - but I don't really want a large CMS, just a image upload place from a mobile app to cloud storage.
or is the problem so simple most people just set it up "by hand" ?

Comment: I'm curious, why discard blob storage?

Comment: when I read other stackoverflows it seems to be the best way to stick to filesystem. and avoid heavy images in database over time - I assumes 1-2 TB of images in a year or two, so I kind of want the images on filesystem - also for later analysing the images in the future.